# positioning multiple backgrounds on same position in all resolutions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website based on FullPage.js and Bootstrap 3, I have a section where on the left side I should have a background image, and on the right side, I should have a text column.

I am having a problem with the background image on the left. The background should be contained within the entire left half of the page (from top to bottom) and keeping the two crossed lines on the eye of the goat in all resolutions.

design example

[image]

I have tried several approaches, but none have worked entirely. I hope someone would be able to help me solve this issue.

Updated with code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="about-goat col-lg-6">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="content-goat">
                    <span class="goat-title">Title</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="col-lg-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam consectetur, dui id posuere blandit, tortor urna feugiat risus, ut sollicitudin ipsum purus nec lacus. Phasellus faucibus tempor consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the code you have created.

Comment: @SanjeevK updated with HTML

Comment: can you post a working demo, html alongwith CSS in JSfiddle or codepen?

Comment: you are using only `col-lg-12` but want it to be responsive..not possible..use either all the responsive classes`col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12` or `col-xs-12`.

Comment: @SanjeevK here is the last working version using SVGs: [codepen](http://codepen.io/Cybergoat/pen/KWgNpp). The problem is, that's on smaller resolutions the goat image won't shrink accordingly I assume it's because of the fixed size of the `background-size`.